# window.onbeforeunload losing values in text box

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload, hiddenfield

I have the following code to check for changes on a form when the user is navigating away

```
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
```

confirmExit is a function which handles the check for changes and whether to display a message to the user. However inside the function the textboxes I need to check are losing their values but any hidden fields are not.

Both controls are being set on Page_Load as below in c#:

```
txtForeName.Text = personDetails.Forename;
ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField("hdnForename", personDetails.Forename);
```

In the markup within the confirmExit function I'm retrieving the values as below:

```
if ($("[id$='_txtForename']").val() != $('#hdnForename').val()) {
    return true; }
```

But as I said the value for the textbox is an empty string while the hidden field has retained its value.

Does anyone know why this might be happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your selector for the textbox works?

Try:

```
console.log('#<%=txtForeName.ClientID%>').val());
```

within onbeforeunload and see whether you get the value displayed in the console.

Comment: I know it's a little long for a comment, but it doesn't seem like an answer.

Comment: @Barmar - I don't have enough info to provide a fuller answer. some of the markup would help but I think that his selector isn't working

Comment: I am positive the selector for the textbox works as it's exactly the same as for when retrieving the value when saving, which does work. (Although I'll try the method you posted as well)

Comment: @Ted I'm not familiar with that syntax and when I tried it I got a compilation error when trying to load the page. Edit: will try to post the most relevant markup as there's heaps of it.

Comment: @atamata - what server language are you using? change `ClientId` to `ClientID` (my bad)

Comment: I'm Using C# server-side

Comment: Ok well that's kind of embarrassing, I changed it to your syntax @Ted and now it works, even though in two separate places in the markup the original syntax does work.

Comment: @atamata - glad to have helped out